# Twilio Click To Call 'no-answer' status in JavaScript client

Tags: c#, javascript, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

Is there any way to know if an outgoing call was not answered using only the Twilio Click To Call JavaScript client?

```
Twilio.Device.disconnect(function (conn) {
    logAndDisplay('Call ended');
});
```

Checking `conn.status()` after a call was not answered is 'closed' (same as if a call was answered) so there is no way to figure out the difference.

Before the JavaScript `disconnect` callback is called the `no-answer` status can be retrieved on the server from `DialCallStatus`. In case that status is not available on the client, is there a way to send the server value and access it on the client?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I could not find how to read a `no-answer` status on the client.

The (hacky) solution was to make an AJAX request to the server to get that status.